# Unable to read excel file using POI and Java for Selenium

Tags: java, excel, selenium

My script is to check two excel files(xlsx exported from web application in different intervals like before updation and after updation) with same number of tabs inside with multiple columns. everything is same but I have to compare the values. I have done it for 4 sets but struggling at 5th set. Unable to read the file. checked with 1) size 2) reduced the sheets 3) deleted some data but no use. sometimes it is reading while debugging 1:10, but in run time it says Null pointer exception.

```
 try {
        // Open the Excel file
        String FileNameforScriptsFilePath = "D:\\Functional Automation   
Data\\Pest WTO with change before.xlsx";
        FileInputStream FileNameforScriptsFile = new 
FileInputStream(FileNameforScriptsFilePath);

        XSSFWorkbook DataCleanBefore = new 
XSSFWorkbook(FileNameforScriptsFile);

//      File DataCleaningBeforeFile=new File("D:\\Functional Automation 
Data\\Pest RTO with change before.xlsx");//all are similar names
//      OPCPackage PestWTOwithchangebeforepkg = 
OPCPackage.open(DataCleaningBeforeFile.getAbsolutePath());
//      XSSFWorkbook DataCleanBefore = new   
XSSFWorkbook(PestWTOwithchangebeforepkg);

XSSFSheet BasicAddressDetailsBeforeSheet = 
DataCleanBefore.getSheet("Basic Address Details");
```

I have tried with SXSSFSheet also, and also as given above in // OPC. Please help, struggling since 4 days.

Comment: Hi, We get nullpointer when any of your variable is declared but not initialized. Cross check all your declared variables whether they are initialized before usage.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your Question:

A few words about the solution-

1. Avoid keeping longer names of the excel sheets (keep it simple e.g. "Input.xlsx")
2. As a better practice avoid putting spaces within filenames, directory names & sheet-name in excel files.
3. Ensure that your excel file name name doesn't ends up with multiple extensions (e.g. "Input.xlsx.xlsx")
4. Always close the `XSSFWorkbook` object after performing the tasks.
5. When you start a `try{}` block, close it properly.
6. `Try{}` block must be at-least followed by a `catch{}` block.
7. Try to catch the `Base Exception`.
8. Keep your code clean, remove unwanted code.
9. Here is your own working code removing all the unwanted codes which opens an excel file "D:\Functional Automation Data Pest WTO with change before.xlsx", reads the sheet "Basic Address Details" and counts the rows in it.

   ```
           try {
               // Open the Excel file
               File FileNameforScriptsFilePath = new File(
                       "D:\\Functional Automation Data Pest WTO with change before.xlsx");
               FileInputStream FileNameforScriptsFile = new FileInputStream(FileNameforScriptsFilePath);
               XSSFWorkbook DataCleanBefore = new XSSFWorkbook(FileNameforScriptsFile);
               XSSFSheet BasicAddressDetailsBeforeSheet = DataCleanBefore.getSheet("Basic Address Details");
               int rowCount = BasicAddressDetailsBeforeSheet.getLastRowNum();
               System.out.println("Total Rows is : " + (rowCount + 1));
               DataCleanBefore.close();
           } catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.println(e);
   ```

Let me know if this helps you.